# Has the "Mäṣḥafä Kedus" (Holy Scriptures) of Beta Israel been translated into English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach, translation, apocrypha

From Wikipedia:

> Mäṣḥafä Kedus (Holy Scriptures) is the name for the religious literature. The language of the writings is Ge'ez. The holiest book is the Orit (from Aramaic "Oraita" – "Torah") which consists of the Five Books of Moses and the books Joshua, Judges and Ruth. The rest of the Bible has secondary importance. Sources are lacking on whether the Book of Lamentations is excluded from the canon, or whether it forms part of the Book of Jeremiah as it does in the Orthodox Tewahedo biblical canon.[citation needed]
>
> Deuterocanonical books that also make up part of the canon are Sirach, Judith, Esdras 1 and 2, Meqabyan, Jubilees, Baruch 1 and 4, Tobit, Enoch and the testaments of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob.
>
> Non-Biblical writings Include: Nagara Muse (The Conversation of Moses), Mota Aaron (Death of Aharon), Mota Muse (Death of Moses), Te'ezaza Sanbat (Precepts of Sabbath), Arde'et (Students), Gorgorios, Mäṣḥafä Sa'atat (Book of Hours), Abba Elias (Father Elija), Mäṣḥafä Mäla'əkt (Book of Angels), Mäṣḥafä Kahan (Book of Priest), Dərsanä Abrəham Wäsara Bägabs (Homily on Abraham and Sarah in Egypt), Gadla Sosna (The Acts of Susanna) and Baqadāmi Gabra Egzi'abḥēr (In the Beginning God Created). Zëna Ayhud (Jews Story) and fālasfā (Philosophers) are two books that are not holy but still have a great influence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haymanot

Have these books all been translated into English? If so, where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most relevant translation into English I could find is probably [*Falasha Anthology*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.188774/page/n0) by Wolf Leslau, which includes the Laws of Sabbath, Abba Elijah, Book of the Angels, Baruch, Apocalypse of Gorgorios, Testament of Abraham, Death of Moses, and Prayers.

Many of the other books are available in any translation of the apocrypha and pseudepigrapha (for example R. H. Charles' *The Apocrypha and Pseudepigrapha of the Old Testament*, vol. [1](https://archive.org/details/CharlesRHTheApocryphaPseudepigraphaOfTheOldTestamentInEnglishVol11913/page/n7), [2](https://archive.org/details/CharlesRHTheApocryphaPseudepigraphaOfTheOldTestamentInEnglishVol21913/page/n3)). Usually the translation isn't based on the Ethiopic translation (notable exceptions are 1 Enoch and Jubilees, which still exist as a complete text *only* in the Ethiopic version). Yosippon, which is also part of the canon (as "Jews Story") is available in an antiquated translation [here](https://archive.org/details/wonderfulmostdep00howe/page/n7), but is also translated from the Hebrew, not from the Ethiopic version.